# having trouble with linked lists

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program where the user can add integers to a linked list and then it will calculate what the largest number is is, what the smallest number is, what the sum of the number are, ect... I am having some trouble with this, I find linked lists to be pretty confusing and am hoping someone could help me out with figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
import java.util.*;
public class UnorderedLinkedListInt extends LinkedListIntClass {
  int size=0;
  LinkedList<Integer> list;

  public boolean isEmptyList(){
    if(size==0){
      return true;
    }else{return false;}
  }
  public void initializeList(){
    list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  }
  public void print(){
    for(int x : list){
      System.out.printf("%s ",x);
    }
  }
  public int length(){
    return size;
  }
  public int front(){
    return list.getFirst();
  }
  public int back(){
    return list.getLast();
  }
  public void insertFirst(int newItem){
    list.addFirst(newItem);
  }
  public void insertLast(int newItem){
    list.addLast(newItem);
  }
  public boolean search(int searchItem){
    return list.contains(searchItem);
  }
  public void deleteNode(int deleteItem){
    list.remove(deleteItem);
  }
  public int findSum(){
    int sum =0;
    for(int x:list){
      sum=sum+x;
    }
    return sum;
  }
  public int findMin(){
    int min =list.get(0);
    for(int i=1;i<list.size();i++){
      if(list.get(i)<min){
        min=list.get(i);
      }
    }
    return min;
  }
  public int findMax(){
    int max=list.get(0);
    for(int i=1;i<list.size();i++){
      if(list.get(i)>max){
        max=list.get(i);
      }
    }
    return max;
  }
}
```

Here is my client method that I am using to test the code.

```
import java.util.*; 
public class ClientUnorderedLinkedListInt { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        UnorderedLinkedListInt intList = new UnorderedLinkedListInt(); 
        UnorderedLinkedListInt tempList; 
        int num; 
        System.out.println("Enter integers (999 to stop)"); 
        num = input.nextInt();//valid??
        while (num != 999) { 
            intList.insertLast((Integer) num); 
            num = input.nextInt();//valid??
        } 
        System.out.print("\nTesting .insertLast and .print. The original list is: "); 
        intList.print(); 
        System.out.println("\nTesting .length. The length of the list is: " + intList.length()); 
        if (!intList.isEmptyList()) { 
            System.out.println("Testing .front. First element/list: " + intList.front()); 
            System.out.println("Testing .back. Last element/list: "  + intList.back()); 
        } 
        System.out.println("Testing .sum. The sum of data in all nodes is: " + intList.findSum()); 
        System.out.println("Testing .min. The smallest data in all nodes is: " + intList.findMin()); 
        System.out.print("Testing .search. Enter the number to search for/list: "); 
        num = input.nextInt(); //valid??
        if (intList.search(num)) 
            System.out.println(num + " found in this list."); 
        else 
            System.out.println(num + " is not in this list."); 
        System.out.print("Testing .remove. Enter the number to be deleted from list: "); 
        num = input.nextInt();//valid??
        intList.deleteNode(num); 
        System.out.print("Testing .toString. After deleting " + num + ", the list is: " + intList); 
        System.out.println("\nThe length of the list after delete is: " + intList.length()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You should tell us about the specific error or issue.  That's a lot of code for us to go through.

Comment: Please do not assume we automatically know what you mean by "wrong". If it compiles please include sample input and output.

Comment: What trouble are you actually encountering? Are you seeing errors / exceptions? What is the desired behaviour vs the actual behaviour?

Comment: You gave code, good.  But you need to provide detail about the issues.  Coming on SO and going, "It doesn't work.  Help me." is like going to a doctor and saying, "I don't feel good."  Give details! "When I do this, it does that." etc.

Comment: when I run the program it asks me "Enter integers (999 to stop)" when I enter an integer I get the following error

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at UnorderedLinkedListInt.insertLast(UnorderedLinkedListInt.java:32)

Comment: So the error is somewhere in the insertLast method something is wrong but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 2):

The size variable isn't being updated when items are added or removed, you should just use the existing methods of the List class when possible (size(), isEmpty(), etc.).

Also you are probably the victim of [auto-boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).  Because your list contains Integers (Objects) you need to verify that you are calling an appropriate method of the List class depending on if you are passing an index or a 'value' Object. The [remove(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) method often trips people up because it is overloaded and can take either a primitive int for indexing or an Integer object for items within the list.

Comment: The size variable isn't even necessary--size() is a built-in method in class LinkedList.

Comment: @La-comadreja I agree there is no need for the variable, but it is there and being used.  Would be better to just use list.size() instead (that goes for the isEmpty() as well).

Answer (score 2):

You do have to call initializeList() or make a constructor that creates a linked list and leaves it in the proper default state.

```
public UnorderedLinkedListInt() {
    super();
    initializeList();
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I get the following error "Error: invalid method declaration; return type required"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other two answers here (so far), I'll add that in the penultimate line of your client class,

```
System.out.print("Testing .toString. After deleting " + num + ", the list is: " + intList);
```

your code as is just prints out `Testing .toString. After deleting 1, the list is: UnorderedLinkedListInt@4a5a12f5` and I think you can see why that might be undesirable.

Try writing a `toString()` method that formats your list; then the code you include will work.